# Populate new column in R from other columns based on conditional statement

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a data frame (data.frame(test)) in R with the following information.

```
Columns1 | Column2 | Column3
1 | 11 | 33
3 | 34 | 56 
4 | 24 | 23
5 | 74 | 64 
3 | 45 | 52
2 | 54 | 53
1 | 76 | 92
```

I am trying to create a new column that is populated by the data in columns 2 and 3 based on a conditional statement of column 1.

I cannot seem to figure out how to write the appropriate conditional.

```
if (test$column1 == 3 || test$column1 == 2 || test$column1 == 1) {
test$Newcolumn = test$column1
} else {
  test$NewColumn = test$column2
}
```

The final result should look like this:

```
Columns1 | Column2 | Column3 | NewColumn 
1 | 11 | 33 | 11
3 | 34 | 56 | 33
4 | 24 | 23 | 23
5 | 74 | 64 | 64
3 | 45 | 52 | 45
2 | 54 | 53 | 54
1 | 76 | 92 | 76
```

Comment: a simple `ifelse` like `ifelse(test$column1 %in% c(1,2,3), test$column2, test$column3)`

Comment: This did it,  thank you.

Comment: glad i could helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution "a simple ifelse like ifelse(test$column1 %in% c(1,2,3), test$column2, test$column3)" by – joel.wilson worked.

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`, assuming `mydf` is your dataframe:

```
mydf %>% mutate(newColumn = ifelse(column1 %in% 1:3, column2, column3)) -> res
```

I assumed there is a typo in your question and you intended to assign `column2` value to `newColumn` in case the condition is met.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a typo. When  I run my code it either populates the new column with only column 1 or only column 2.